# How to implement AES PKCS5Padding using Objective-c

Tags: ios, aes

I found that there is no `PKCS5Padding` padding on iOS. How can I implement an AES encryption using `PKCS5Padding`?

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31769026/451475)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES always has a block size of 16 bytes. PKCS #5 padding is only defined for 8 byte blocks. So this combination is invalid. I don't know where your got that requirement from.

However, PKCS #7 padding is the same padding mechanism but it's defined for different block sizes. PKCS #7 for 8 byte blocks is the same as PKCS #5.

So most likely you want to use PKCS #7, which is available on iOS.

Comment: I got a java backend using PKCS5Padding . So I have to make encryption using PKCS5Padding.

Comment: @dee Codo is right, use PKCS#7. See [my explanation on the crypto site](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172)

Comment: @dee I assume Java is silently switching to PKCS #7.

Comment: @Codo You mean Java can change PKCS #5 to PKCS7 silently?

Comment: PKCS#5Padding is only specified for a block size up to 8-bytes while PKCS#7Padding is specified for a block size up to 255-bytes. See Wikipedia: [Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)). IOW PKCS#7Padding can be used in place of PKCS#5Padding.